# Using pygame on macOS Sierra: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game using pygame. I am getting an error.  I suspect the error might have something to do with the fact that I'm running this program on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6. Here's the code so far:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((550, 550))

pygame.display.set_caption("Tic Tac Toe")
```